# URL Based splitting webapps and Reverse Proxying

Tags: web-applications, reverse-proxy

Suppose I have two webapp running on the same machine but **different** stacks and codebases.

First for user profiles

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile

Second is for homepage

- http://127.0.0.1:30000/

**How to combine these web apps to a *one combined* web app?**

Like:

- http://local.site/profile
- http://local.site/

---

Do I need reverse proxy/web servers

- Nginx
- Varnish
- Apache
- Haproxy

And which method should I use?

- Redirect
- Rewrite
- Or another method?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Below does the trick.

```
http {

    upstream home {
        server 172.17.0.3;
        server 172.17.0.5;
        server 172.17.0.7;

    }
    upstream about {
        server 172.17.0.4;                               
        server 172.17.0.6;                               

    }

   # (...)

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://home;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /about.html {
            proxy_pass http://about;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }        
    }
}
```